# Probability, objects going around a table

Tags: probability

Two balls are moved around a table. At each time step, either the red ball moves to the left with probability $p$ or the green ball moves to the right with probability $q=1-p$. There are $F>2$ positions in total around the table. The red ball's position is denoted by $0,1,2...$, the green ball's position is denoted by $F, F-1, F-2$ etc.

[image: table]

Below I am posting questions related to this problem and my solutions. I would be grateful for corrections/suggestions.

1) What is the probability that the red ball manages to complete one full circuit while the green remains stationary?

$$p^F$$
2) What is the probability, $p_n$, that the Red and Green first meet at position
$n$?
$$p_n = { F \choose n}p^n (1-p)^{F-n}$$

3) What is the mean position of the first meeting of the balls and its variance?
$$\mu = pF,\hspace{35pt} \sigma^2 = p(1-p)F$$

4) What is the probability $p_n^s$ that the red and green first meet at position $n$ with the red having been first to arrive there?

*I'm not sure how to make it different from 2) and it's stopping me from solving the next points.*

5) What is the probability that the red reaches position $n$ before the green gets there, as a sum of terms of the form $p_n$ and $p_n^s$ for suitable $n$.

6) Hence prove:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{F-n-1} {n-1+k \choose k} p^n q^k = {F-1 \choose n} p^n q^{F-n}+ \sum_{k=n+1}^F {F \choose k}p^kq^{F-k}$$

Comment: For 2) you forgot the binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question $4$, it is the same as the probability that at time $F-1$ the red ball is at position $n$ and the green ball is at position $F-(n+1)$, multiplied by the probability that the green ball moves to the left, i.e.
$$
  p_n^s
= \binom{F-1}{n}p^nq^{F - (n+1)}\cdot q
= \binom{F-1}{n}p^n q^{F - n}.
$$
For question $5$, this is the probability that the balls either meet at position $n$ with the red ball arriving first, i.e. $p_n^s$, or the balls meet at some point $k > n$, thus it is
$$
  p_n^s + \sum_{k=n+1}^F p_n
= \binom{F-1}{n}p^n q^{F - n} + \sum_{k=n+1}^F\binom{F}{k}p^k q^{F - k},
$$
which is the term on the right of your last equation.

Comment: Thanks. Any comments on the LHS of the last equation?